# Grails with Spring Security plugin not redirecting from http to https when using REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: grails, https, amazon-web-services, spring-security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Grails 2.1 with the Spring Security plugin.  I have some paths that have REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL set.  When I run my app on my machine with “grails run-app -https” everything works properly when accessing a path that requires https from http (they get redirected).  However, on the Amazon Elastic Beanstalk paths requiring https do not redirect from http to https.

I have set

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
```

in Config.groovy for production and

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = false
```

in Config.groovy for development.

If I telnet to port 80 and request a path that has REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL set, this is what I see on the Amazon Elastic Beanstalk:

```
$ telnet www.example.com 80
Connected to www.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /login/index HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://www.example.com/login/index
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 19:40:29 GMT
```

If I telnet to port 8080 using the development environment and request a path that has REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL set, this is what I see on my machine:

```
$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /server/login/index HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: https://localhost:8443/server/login/index
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 19:27:09 GMT
```

How do I get my app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk to properly forward paths that have REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL set from http to https?

Comment: [This stackoverflow.com question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571806/grails-and-aws-enforcing-ssh-https?rq=1) appears to be discussing the same problem.  However, it does not say if the person is using Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: I wonder if this offers a clue? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=219980#219980

Comment: Thanks @andrew ! It seems as I will be needing a custom AMI to solve the issue. I will be trying the solution laid out in the Amazon AWS forum you pointed out as soon as possible.

Comment: What is your value for grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName? Shouldn't it be x-forwarded-proto?

Comment: @andrew I updated my AMI to ami-1624987f (was using ami-aecd60c7).  It has ProxyPreserveHost on in /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf and the valve mentioned in the post you pointed me to in /etc/tomcat7/server.xml

Comment: @Joel I have the following settings: grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'

Comment: Can you confirm in the code that those headers are being set? Seems like your config.groovy is correct so it seems to me that either (a) the header isn't being set or (b) there's something subtle wrong int he grails config. I would check (a) first. Let me know if you can print the value of X-Forwarded-Proto.

Comment: @Joel, I wrote a small test app as you suggested.  It is available on [github](https://github.com/yencarnacion/testhttps).  It looks to me like the request headers are being set correctly.  I now believe that as Andrew suggested, the issue lies in a server configuration problem.  It seems to me that the Amazon EC2 instance's reverse proxy is rewriting the urls and causing the problem.  Because the issue is a server configuration issue, it would seem like the answer to the question falls outside of the scope of StackOverflow.  I may continue the question on ServerFault or the AWS forums.